# Sort scientific and float

Tags: shell, sorting, floating-point

I have been trying desperately to use the command `sort`, to sort a mixture out of scientific and floating values which are both positive and negative, e.g.:

```
-2.0e+00
2.0e+01
2.0e+02
-3.0e-02
3.0e-03
3.0e-02
```

Without the floating point or without the scientific exponent, it works just fine with
`sort -k1 -g file.dat`. Using both at once as stated before, it results in:

```
-3.0e-02
-2.0e+00
2.0e+01
2.0e+02
3.0e-02
3.0e-03
```

This is obviously wrong since it should be:

```
-2.0e+00    
-3.0e-02
3.0e-03
3.0e-02
...
```

Any idea how I can solve this issue? And once I solve this, is there any possibility to sort the absolute value (e.g. get rid of the negative ones)? I know I could try to square each value, sort, take the square root. Doing this I would be less precise though and it would be neat to have a nice, fast and straightforward way.

My linux system: 8.12, Copyright © 2011

Thank you very much!

UPDATE: if I run it in the debug mode `sort -k1 -g filename.dat --debug` I get the following result (I translated it into english, output was german)

```
 sort: the sorting rules for „de_DE.UTF-8" are used
 sort: key 1 is numerically and involves several fields
-3.0e-02
__
________
-2.0e+00
__
________
2.0e+01
_
_______
2.0e+02
_
_______
3.0e-02
_
_______
3.0e-03
_
_______
```

Comment: it's not "wrong". it's just sorting as a string. `-n` might help, though I don't know if it'll handle float values.

Comment: @MarcB: Note that he *is* using numerical sorting (`-g`) to begin with.

Comment: yep,    [-n]      doesn't produce the correct output as well, tried that one before

Comment: Googling for "linux 8.12" comes up with Kiwi Linux; does that sound correct?

Comment: I can't reproduce this; I get the correct result. My sort version is 8.13.

Comment: SUSE Linux Enterprise Desktop 11 (x86_64)
VERSION = 11
PATCHLEVEL = 2

Comment: @Jan: Unfortunately there's no cut-and-dried way to determine what distribution / version you are running on. The file `/etc/issue` might give a good hint.

Comment: I don't have permission to use the command `/etc/isse`. I seem to have the `SUSE distribution release 11`

Comment: @Evert: This is *really* strange... I can reproduce this error with `sort` 8.21 (Mint 17, giving the same *wrong* results as OP), but *cannot* reproduce it with the older `sort` 8.12 (SLES 11 SP 3, giving *correct* output with `-g`)...?!?

Comment: @Jan: `cat /etc/issue` for *printing* the file, not `/etc/issue` for *executing* it. Anyway, we're already one step beyond that. ;-) Looks like a nice little regression you've stepped into. ;-)

Comment: Try running `sort` with the `--debug` option. Further, check the locales on the machines. Try e.g. `LC_ALL=C sort -k1 -g inputfile`.

Comment: Jan: what does the command `locale` give you?

Comment: `sort -k1 -g einfach.dat --debug` still gives the same wrong result.
If I type `LC_ALL=C sort -k1 -g inputfile` he says he doesn't know the command `LC_ALL=C`

Comment: @Evert : LANG=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=

Comment: Just verified that running either of "my" versions (8.21, 8.12) with `LANG=C` doesn't do anything for the output. (The Mint is the same config as Jan's, the SLES is en_US.UTF-8.)

Comment: The point of `--debug` was not whether it returns the correct result, but that it gives  more, possibly relevant, information. You can [update](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/26339232/edit) your question with the extra output you get.

Comment: @Evert: I updated my question with the requested information

Comment: Thanks. Btw, why should -3.0e-02 come before -2.0e+00? (The paragraph starting with "This is obviously wrong".)

Comment: @Evert: Yes, you are right, I made a mistake there. I updated my question accordingly. However, the sorting order is still not correct

Comment: Also, did you copy-paste that `--debug` output? Because for me it says "is numeric and spans multiple fields", not what you have ("... numerically and involves ...").

Comment: It works in `sort (GNU coreutils) 5.93` with both `LC_ALL=""` and `LC_ALL="C"` on Mac OS X.

Comment: To check the locale effect another way, you could try `| tr . , | sort ...` to replace the `.` with `,` and see if that changes anything for your locale. (Note, I don't suggest this as a fix, just as a test for troubleshooting)

Comment: @Evert: I did not copy paste it since I have a german version. As I have written above the `--debug` text I translated it myself. I suppose it says the same as your version so there is probably nothing wrong here.
@hyde: looks like it solved the problem. I will test it with the real file not with the test numbers I used

Comment: @hyde: no, unfortunately it did not work either :-(

Comment: @hyde: thanks a lot, it did work! I checked again carefully (as it is hard to not be confused by thousands of data points). If I change the `.` to `,` the sorting works with the `-g` parameter.

Answer (score 3):

Based on comments under the question, this is a locale issue: `sort` is using a locale, which expects `,` as decimal separator, while your text has `.`. Ideal solution would to make `sort` use a different locale, and hopefully someone will write a correct answer covering that.

But, if you can't, or don't want to, change how `sort` works, then you can change the input it gets. This is easiest by making `sort` take its input from pipe, and modify it on the way. Here it is enough to change every `.` to `,`, so the tool of choice is [`tr`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tr):

```
cat file.dat | tr . , | sort -k1 -g
```

This solution has one big drawback: if command is executed with locale where sort uses `.` as decimal separator, then instead of fixing, this will break the sorting. So if you are writing a shell script, which may be used elsewhere, don't do this.

Important note: Above command has [unnecessary use of *cat*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16279/should-i-care-about-unnecessary-cats). Everybody who wants themselves to be taken seriously as professional shell script programmers, don't do that!

Comment: You can get rid of UUoc with `tr . , < file.dat`. Well done for discovering the issue was with dots / commas!

Comment: I just ran into precisely the same issue, and boy am I glad I found this enlightening comment. I should have noticed that the same command gave correct results on my laptop with US locale!  At any rate thank you.

Comment: Thank you, `LANG="C"` also fixes the issue.