# Sorting using -k

Tags: shell, sorting, unix

I tried this solution to my list and I can't get what I want after sorting.

I got list:

```
m_2_mdot_3_a_1.dat    ro=  303112.12
m_1_mdot_2_a_0.dat    ro=  300.10
m_2_mdot_1_a_3.dat    ro=  221.33
m_3_mdot_1_a_1.dat    ro=  22021.87
```

I used `sort -k 2 -n >name.txt`
I would like to get list from the lowest `ro` to the highest `ro`. What I did wrong?
I got a sorting but by the names of 1 column or by last value but like: `1000, 100001, 1000.2` ... It sorted like by only 4 meaning numbers or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cat test.txt | tr . , | sort -k3 -g | tr , .
```

The following link gave a good answer [Sort scientific and float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26339232/sort-scientific-and-float)

In brief,

1. you need -g option to sort on decimal numbers;
2. the -k option start
       from 1 not 0;
3. and by default locale, ***sort*** use **,** as seperator
       for decimal instead of **.**

However, be careful if your name.txt contains **,** characters

Answer (score 0):

Since there's a space or a tab between `ro=` and the numeric value, you need to sort on the 3rd column instead of the 2nd. So your command will become:

```
cat input.txt | sort -k 3 -n
```